# Problem : Getting a mobile drive size using C# throws exception - Commented

Tags: c#

when i run this code :

```
CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2 FolderInfo;
int iResult = 0;
IntPtr Buffer =  Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2)));                
iResult = CONAFileSystem.CONAFindNextFolder(hFindHandle, Buffer);
while (iResult == PCCSErrors.CONA_OK )
{
 FolderInfo = (CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Buffer,typeof(CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2));                                                             
    //......................... i got an error msg here as follows:
    // Error Messege: 
       FatalExecutionEngineError was detected Message: The runtime has encountered a 
       fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x7a0ba769, on thread 0x1294. The
       error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe 
       or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include 
       user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

how to use CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2, coz when i use  CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO it only gives me the name and lable of the device
but when is use CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2 it gives me freeSize and TotalSize

please help

Comment: Why this question is voted down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what that error means but if you want to get the drive's size, you can use

```
        DriveInfo di = new DriveInfo("f");  //Put your mobile drive name
        long totalBytes = di.TotalSize;
        long freeBytes = di.TotalFreeSpace;
```

Comment: ok it worked but it returns the size in terms of what (Bytes,KByte,MByte ,GByte )?!?

Comment: it's in bytes... you just have to convert it to whatever unit that you want, divide it by 1024 to get KB, divide by 1024 again to get MB and so on...

Comment: Dear leon this function gives me the size of my local dirves ("c:\", "E:\")but not the mobile derives ?!?!?!

Comment: i tried this on a flash drive and it worked.  what type of mobile drive are you using?

Comment: my application works on S60 and i'm working on mass storage and MMC

Comment: @Eng.Basma, you should mention your environment in your question, not everyone is reading all comments.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that you get the exception when you try and convert the data in the buffer to a different type of structure than was originally created by CONAFileSystem.CONAFindNextFolder.

You are trying to force a data structure of type CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO into a structure of type CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2. They almost certainly have different lengths and so on so its extremely unlikely this method would ever work.

From experience with C++ development on the Symbian OS, the pattern Nokia are likely to be using here is one where they have subsequently developed a newer version of the API and so have created a newer version of the CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO structure (i.e. CONADefinitions.CONAPI_FOLDER_INFO2).

Assuming this is correct there are 3 likelihoods:

1) There is an enum parameter to the first function which specifies which version of the output structure is to be created.

2) There is a new function which returns the new structure e.g. CONAFileSystem.CONAFindFirstFolder2, CONAFileSystem.CONAFindNextFolder2

3) Nokia have developed the new version internally but not yet released it publicly.